# How to copy a file and then save it with a dynamic filename using python

Tags: python, linux, scripting, ubuntu-14.04, python-3.4

Example:
I am taking a name from user, lets say:

domainName = input("Enter domain name:")

os.system(cp etc/default etc/domainName)

Here the file will be copied with the name domainName but I want to save it with a name that is stored in variable *domainName*? How do I do this ?

Comment: This isn't directly related to your problem, but consider using [`shutil.copyfile`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html#shutil.copyfile) instead of `os.system`.

Comment: @Kevin : your solution works same as cp command but it doesn't solve my problem

Comment: By "solution", do you mean my "use `copyfile`" comment, or the actual solution I posted?

Comment: By solution I meant your string concatenation answer. Although I have switched to using subprocess instead of os.system.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I don't recommend using `os.system` to copy files. That said...

How about string concatenation?

```
os.system("cp etc/default etc/" + domainName)
```

Comment: It works, thank you. what would you suggest for executing terminal commands through python code?

Comment: `system` does work for simple terminal commands. The `subprocess` module gives you some additional capabilities, ex. reading the result of the command, interactive sessions, etc. But generally, one should avoid using terminal commands at all if there is a native Python alternative. That's why I suggested `copyfile`.